# how to push docker images to nexus3 repository without the usage of docker commands?

Tags: docker, curl, nexus3

Can anybody please let me know on how to push docker images to nexus3 repository (where i have hosted a docker repo) without the usage of docker commands ?

I believe we can use curl command but i would want to know the full syntax of curl command  to push docker images to nexus3 docker repo.

This is required for us as part of alternative/interim approach for the next one month.

Any ideas/ suggestions would be of much helpful.

Comment: Have you tried modifying this?: https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-authenticate-with-the-v2-api